# Calling on a column from a data frame within a data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data frame (lets call that "data") that I have generated which goes something like this:

```
$"something.csv"
   x  y  z
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3

$"something else.csv"
   x  y  z
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
```

I would like to output from the table "something.csv" one number within column x.

So far I have used:

```
data$"something.csv"$x[2]
```

This coding works and I am happy that it does, but my problem is that I want to automate this process and so i have put all the table titles into a list (filename) which goes:

```
[1] "something.csv", "something else.csv"
```

So i made a for loop which should allow me to do so but when I put in:

```
data$filename[1]$x[2]
```

it gives me back NULL.

When i print `filename[1]`, I get `[1] "something.csv"` and if I type

```
data$"something.csv"$x[2]
```

I get the result I want. so if `filename[1] = "something.csv"`, why does it not give me the same results?

I just want my code to out put the second row of column x and automate by using `filename[i]` in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have tried to approach the problem tries to find a column 'filename[1]' from the list, but it is not found. Hence, the NULL gets returned.

You need to use square brackets, and subset the object data. Here's an example:

```
# Generate data
data<-vector("list", 2)
names(data)<-c("something.csv", "something else.csv")
data[[1]]<-data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3, z=1:3)
data[[2]]<-data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3, z=1:3)
filename<-names(l)

# Subset the data
# The first data frame, notice the square brackets for subsetting lists!
data[[filename[1]]]
# column x
data[[filename[1]]]$x
# Second observation of x
data[[filename[1]]]$x[2]
```

The above uses for subsetting the names of the objects in the list. You can also use the number-based subsetting suggested by @Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `[` and `[[` to call `data$"something.csv"$x[2]` try

```
data[[1]][2,1]
```

where `[[1]]` is the first list element and `[2,1]` is the data frame reference element